# Aperiodic set of corner Wang Tile

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, computability-theory, tiling

There is quite some reference on aperiodicity of the edge-type of Wang Tile. But I could not yet find aperiodic corner type of Wang Tiles... Could someone provide me some instances (better with reference) of aperiodic Wang Tile of corner-type? Thank you:)

Comment: If you believe the answer to your previous question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164400/relationship-between-corner-tile-and-edge-tile-of-wang-tile which you accepted, then an aperiodic edge-type Wang tile translates directly to an aperiodic corner-type Wang tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I read the answer to [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164400/relationship-between-corner-tile-and-edge-tile-of-wang-tile). I believe it's correct. This gives a recipe to translate any edge-type Wang tile to a corner-type Wang tile. If you start with an aperiodic set of edge-type Wang tiles, then the corner-type Wang tiles you get from this construction are also aperiodic. What more is there to say?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a the minimal known instances of corner-type aperiodic Wang Tile....

Comment: So if that's what you're looking for, this should be made clear in your question. At this point, you should have enough information to find references yourself using google. The best edge type Wang tiling is the Kari-Culik tiling. Any literature on corner Wang tilings will certainly refer to that.